# How to calculate the total price of the shopping cart using LocalStorage

Tags: php, html, xampp, local-storage, thread-local-storage

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wSnQ1Ew-hzpezVcEM46Rlh23E7AWYL1l/view?usp=sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYIpw.png)

(image link)

I'm trying to calculate the total price of the cart but i'm not sure how should I write the code, can someone help me?

```
<script>
  document.querySelector("#updateCart").addEventListener('click',function()
  {
    document.querySelector('#prod_value').innerText = localStorage.getItem("prod_value")
    document.querySelector('#prod_qty').innerText = localStorage.getItem("prod_qty")
    document.querySelector('#prod_size').innerText = localStorage.getItem("prod_size")
  })
  document.querySelector("#updateCart").addEventListener('click',function()
  {
    document.querySelector('#prod2_value').innerText = localStorage.getItem("prod2_value")
    document.querySelector('#prod2_qty').innerText = localStorage.getItem("prod2_qty")
    document.querySelector('#prod2_size').innerText = localStorage.getItem("prod2_size")
  })

  document.querySelector("#updateCart").addEventListener('click',function()
  {
    document.querySelector('#total').innerText = localStorage.getItem('prod_value' + 'prod2_value')
  })
</script>
```

the #total i created wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

```
let valueOne = localStorage.getItem("prod_value")
let valueTwo = localStorage.getItem("prod2_value")
let total = valueOne + valueTwo

document.querySelector('#total').innerText = total
```

Comment: it became 329.00399.00